# User Removal Script (Powershell)

Tags: powershell

I'm in the process of creating a script that will ask for a computer name, list all users on the pc, and prompt for removal. My current code does everything except for actually check if the profile exists and removing the profile. I continue to get "Invalid Entry." Please help. I'm also aware that this is probably a more complicated way of doing things but I just want to make it as easy as possible for other techs to use my script if needed.

```
    $computer = read-host "Enter computer name"
    Do {
    $profileName = read-host "enter profile name for removal (exit to quit, list to show users)
    $path = "C:\Users\" + profileName
    if((Test-path "$path") -Like "$profileName") {
    get-ciminstance -computername localhost, $computer -classname win32_userprofile |
    where-object {$_.LocalPath.split('\')[-1] -eq $profileName } |
    Remove-Ciminstance
    Write-host "profile removed." }
    elseif($profileName -eq "list") {
    get-ciminstance -computername $computer -classname win32_userprofile |
    where-object{$_.localpath} |
    select-object -expandproperty localpath }
    elseif($profileName -eq "exit") {
    write-host "exiting script."
    break }
    else {
    write-host "invalid entry." }
    } until ($profileName -eq "exit")
```

Comment: I think your use of the `-Like` operator is wrong. Are you looking for `-Like "*$profileName"`? Because as you have put it, the expression always should evaluate to `false`, explaining your error of "invalid entry".

Comment: Also, wouldn't `(Test-path "$path")` evaluate to a boolean, making the comparison to the string of `$profileName` rather useless?

Answer (score 1):

I usually do like an excludedprofile list Admin/Myself etc... that checks for it and then i do whatever i want to do, hope it helps:

```
$excludedprofiles= 'PEPE','PIPO'
$userfolder=Get-ItemProperty ('C:\users\*')
$userfolder | foreach {
        if ($excludedprofiles -notcontains $_.Name){
        #Whatever u want to do in here
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$profileName = read-host "enter profile name for removal (exit to quit, list to show users)
$path = "C:\Users\" + profileName
if((Test-path "$path") -Like "$profileName") {
    [...]
}
else {
    write-host "invalid entry."
}
```

This code is probably the reason you get the output of "invalid entry". As I suspected in the comments, when I tested this, I got several errors. First in the line `$path = "C:\Users\" + profileName` where it should be `$profileName`, but I guess that was a typo when creating the question.

Then, the big problem is that your `if` expression always evaluates to false, and for multiple reasons:

1. `(Test-path "$path")` returns a boolean, so always `true` or `false`. A comparison with the value of `$profileName` will always fail, as the profil name will be a string.
2. Even the expression `"$path" -Like "$profileName"` will fail, as path is some string plus the value of `profileName`, so they are always different. You need the wildcard here: `"$path" -Like "*$profileName"`

So, in conclusion the expression you are looking for is probably `if((Test-path "$path") -and ("$path" -Like "*$profileName"))`, which tests the validity of the path and then compares the path to the profile name with wildcard.